# php get google place details from business name

Tags: php, google-places-api

I want to pull business data from google places ip. I can do that by using place_id with the code below;

```
$name = urlencode('Business name');
$place_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid='.$place_id.'&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$jsonContent = json_decode($json, TRUE);

$jsonContent['result']['name'];
$jsonContent['result']['formatted_phone_number'];
$jsonContent['result']['formatted_address'];
$jsonContent['result']['website'];
$jsonContent['result']['place_id'];
```

What I want to be able to do is the get business data using business name or get place_id by using business name so i can use the code above to pull the data. Obtaining the the place id with business name is possible on the following link;

[Google place ID finder](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id)

Can anyone help with how i can obtain either business data using business name or obtain place id using business name?

Comment: How do you plan to distinguish businesses with the same name? You can do it manually in browser and then pass the id to php https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder

Comment: The business names i have are all unique so it wont be problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your businesses have unique names, you can use [web API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) for that.

```
$url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=5000&name=BestBusiness&key=YOUR_API_KEY';
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($json);
```

Get id out of `$data` and enjoy it.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. I have tried this but this doesn't only give only one result, it gives 20 results.

Comment: Well, looks like you have a lot of business with the same name. Read the docs. If you have exact location, you can get one by taking a small radius.

Comment: The results I get has different names and the locations are different. Also using the radius is not possible as the business are located nationally. But i will try changing the code a little and see what happens. It seems to me that it is not possible to use only business name.

Comment: Check the API link. Only `query` and `key` are obligatory.