# Google Place ID on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I've been looking for a few weeks now but I can't find any answer…

I own a wordpress website and I have a form that users fill with their address (the address is autocompleted by google). The form is formated thanks to Gravity Form

I need to convert the address with a Place ID.

Do you guys have any idea by any chance ?

Thanks !

Amaury

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47259690/php-get-google-place-details-from-business-name    See if helps?

Comment: Thanks but that's not compatible with the form i'm using …